# ASP.NET site memory use up to 99% if IIS app pool NOT enable 32-bit applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, perfview

We have a ASP.NET MVC3 site on a 8GB memory Windows server 2019, when I enable 32bit applications on of IIS app pool, the site running well, cpu and memory use(about 300MB) of w3wp.exe also low and noraml. But if I disable 32bit applications of IIS app pool, the memory use will rise to 99%. Anyone knows why? 
I dumped memory when up to 99% by perfview, it says System.Globalization object consumed the memory, but I'm not sure. Please help, Thanks in advance!
[image: memory dump]

[image: memory dump2]

Comment: you may want to search existing Q&A's and potential pose this question to the sister site [ServerFault community](https://serverfault.com/) as it pertains to administering and monitoring.  please review the [ServerFault on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).  Having said, I wouldn't necessarily construe this as off-topic to SO.

Comment: as a wild guess, does your MVC application use a bundler that is registered as an IIS or ASP.NET Module?

Comment: @BrettCaswell no bundler

Comment: Could you please paste a screenshot with all columns included (Inc %, Inc etc.)? And please clear the GroupPats text box so Perfview will do no grouping. Also, which type of memory are you checking? Is it private bytes?

Comment: dumped w3wp.exe process memory, see 2nd image.